# Can FFC/FPC connectors use in high voltage but lower current applications?

Tags: voltage, pcb, current, connector, wire

[product page](https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/search_e.php?type=1&id=5&page=1)

FVMC 0.2 mm pitch connector supports 50V 200mA which is 10 Watt power,

my application 100V 8mA, can I use above connector in my application since wattage is 0.8 Watt

Comment: how about if u skip 1 pin unconnected ? .. to achieve 100v insulation .. im asking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to expand on @SpehroPefhany’s answer. For wiring and cables, you cannot look at the combination as wattage. Voltage and amperage are each considered separately and controlled by different aspects:

- Voltage is generally limited by insulation. Excessive voltage will cause breakdown of the insulation and, in extreme cases, arcing between conductors or to ground.
- Amperage is instead limited by conductor resistance which results from conductor material and area. Excessive current results in conductor heating and, in extreme cases, insulation melting or even the conductor melting.

Thus, you cannot trade off between voltage and current.

Answer (score 5):

The manufacturer's limits both apply simultaneously. You can draw no more than 200mA (regardless of voltage) and the voltage cannot exceed 50V (regardless of current).

It may be possible to skip a position and have it work safely at 100V. The manufacturer may be able to advise.

Answer (score 0):

250V/mm is based on exposed conductor creapage contamination reduced from clean  air insulation of 3kV/mm for parallel lines and 1kV/mm for sharp points.

- if exposed conductors were encapsulated in RTV silicone you can use 500V/mm to 1kV/mm (0.1mm gap?) if smooth and if thick enough to retard moisture ingress.  Then removal is possible but not convenient.  you might be able to get more and with current limiting , the power damage is manageable.  The 0.2mm pitch is not the worst case gap.